# What are the differences between the express-handlebars, express-hbs and hbs modules,

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, template-engine

I'm trying to use Handlebars with Express, and I found the modules express-handlebars, express-hbs and hbs which all seem to work similarly. What are the main differences between them that I should be aware of, given that I need to able to use layouts and partials?

Comment: i think you need go through the Readme of the packages, see which suits your needs https://github.com/donpark/hbs, https://github.com/barc/express-hbs, https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars .. All of them support partials, layouts. One advice choose a package which is widely used and has active development. https://github.com/donpark/hbs this one has active development. Other 2 are last released on april and march. & https://github.com/donpark/hbs this one has less issues compared to others. Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 24):

Looks like the comment above needs to be updated a bit.

Updated list is here:

1. [Express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars)

Seems to be the most popular package at the moment. There is live chat on [gitter](https://gitter.im/ericf/express-handlebars?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge). Dependencies are up-to date and current npm version is `3.0.0`. Last update 29 days ago (*at the moment of this post*) One important thing is about its license - it's licensed by [`Yahoo Inc`](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars/blob/master/LICENSE) (others are `MIT` licensed).

There is really good documentation in README with extended explanation of every feature including API information. Here you will find both basic and advanced usage.

One difference in comparison with other packages is an ability to use `Hooks`. In this way you can override some functionality of `ExpressHandlebars` instances.

2. [hbs](https://github.com/donpark/hbs)

Easy to use view engine with almost the same functionality as in `Express-handlebars`, but last activity was 4 months ago. Anyway tests are green at the moment. Has `MIT` license.

3. [Express-hbs](https://github.com/barc/express-hbs)

This package is written by guys from [Barc](http://barc.com/). Can be used with both express 3/4 versions.
It says about `i18n` support which is good, but it's also easy to integrate [i18n](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) everywhere else so I'd not say it's a *feature*. Has `MIT` license.

Comment: They all seem abandoned now - what should be used instead?